# Form nao descarrega da memória

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Ola pessoal preciso de ajuda. Meu `form` não descarrega da memória então não consigo chamá-lo de novo.
Segue código abaixo:

```
If formage=nil then
Begin
```

Crio o form e no `onclose` do `form`

```
Action:=cafree:
Formage:=nil
```

Alguém tem uma ideia???

Comment: De que maneira você cria o *Form*? Ou ele já é carregado na memória ao inicializar a aplicação? Outra pergunta, você o abre com `.Show` ou `.ShowModal`?

Comment: Entao crio o form em run com tform.create (self) ai exibo com show pq com modal nao consigo chamar outra tela....

Comment: Uma pergunta bem curiosa, você está usando ferramenta fmx para desenvolver aplicativos Android?

Comment: Repare na documentação da própria **Embarcadero** (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Forms.TForm.OnClose) que o *caFree* já libera o *form* da memória. Então presumo que haja alguma outra coisa errada na forma que os *forms* estão sendo carregados para a memória.

Comment: Entao gente estou criando ele assim formage:=tformage.create (self); formage.show; lembrando q marquei ele pra ser criado em runtime....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Gente resolvi assim:
O *formage* cria o *formaux*...no *formaux* tem um *button* que faz o q preciso e chama de novo o `formage.show`; O *formage* volta pra tela....quando clico no *checkbox* ele verifica de novo se o *formaux* é *nil* e chama de novo fechando o ciclo..

Comment: Está muito confusa sua resposta, se conseguir melhorar a explicação facilitará bastante se outros usuários tiverem a mesma dúvida.

Comment: Me deparei com o mesmo problema e corrigi dessa maneira: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/254155/erro-criando-novas-telas-no-delphi-para-android/254277#254277

Answer (score 2):

Remova do procedimento `OnClose` os 2 procedimentos informados.
E após a exibição do Formulário (que logicamente ocorreu após a criação)
você aplica a destruição:

```
formage := Tformage.Create(Application);
formage.ShowModal;
FreeAndNil(formage);
```

Observe que após a Exibição é chamado o método de detruição! Esta é a meneira correta de controlar a memória.Lembrando que o Delphi é fraco nesse gerenciamento.
Ou seja, dentro do formulário `formage` você deve controlar a criação e destruição de suas variáveis.

Comment: O problema é se o programador não usa `ShowModal`, aí o controle de liberação de memória tem de ser diferente.

Comment: Sim, sem `ShowModal` ele perde o controle, teria que implementar um Timer e ficar pesquisando Variável X para saber se é hora do `FreeAndNil(formage)`. Ai é muita Gambiarra.

Comment: Ta entao cancelo o onclose... e destruo com o free.... e nao poderia ser com dispeseof??

Comment: O correto é o FreeAndNil(objeto);