# Erro criando novas telas no Delphi para Android

Tags: android, delphi

Estou criando um aplicativo para *Android* com *Delphi 10 Tokyo* e neste aplicativo tem uma determinada tela, chamada *Tela1*. Quando eu clico no botão abrir do meu menu na tela principal, chamando a tela *Tela1*, abre normalmente.

Se eu pressionar outro botão de menu com objetivo de abrir uma "Tela 2" (por exemplo), eu faço uma verificação se existe alguma outra tela aberta e forço seu fechamento antes de abrir a *Tela 2*.

Porém, se eu pressionar o botão de abertura de uma tela que já está aberta, mesmo forçando seu fechamento antes de tentar abri-la novamente, dará erro.

Rodando esse aplicativo no *Windows* bastou colocar um `Application.ProcessMessages` conforme mostrado na rotina abaixo e resolveu o problema.

Mas no *Android* dá erro, pois fala que a tela já está aberta, mesmo forçando seu fechamento.

Como corrijo este problema?

Botão *ABRIR TELA 1* (igual para a *TELA 2*)

```
procedure TfPrincipal.retMenu1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if not CloseForms(Sender) then Exit;

   Application.CreateForm(TfTela1, fTela1);
end;
```

Evento *OnClose* da *TELA 1* (igual para a *TELA 2*)

```
procedure TfTela1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
   Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
   TForm(Sender) := nil;
end;
```

Rotina que força o fechamento de telas já abertas

```
function TfPrincipal.CloseForms(Sender: TObject): Boolean;
var i: Integer;
begin           
   Result := False;

   try
      // Este código não está garantindo o fechamento das telas no Android

      for i := 0 to Application.ComponentCount -1 do
         if Application.Components[i] is TForm then
            if TForm(Application.Components[i]).ClassType <> TfPrincipal then begin
               TForm(Application.Components[i]).Close;
               Application.ProcessMessages;
            end;

      Result := True;
   except on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Erro fechando forms: ' + E.Message);
   end;
end;
```

[RESPOSTA CORRETA POSTADA LOGO ABAIXO, DIFERENTE DO POST DO AUTOR DA OUTRA QUESTÃO]

Comment: Realmente parece ser o mesmo problema, mas como comentou o Andrey na resposta que o próprio autor deu como certo, está tão confuso que não dá para entender bem o que foi feito. A impressão é que foi feita uma gambiarra... No meu problema, a impressão que dá é que falta apenas uma rotina que execute o ProcessMessages corretamente no Android também, pois sem isso dá o mesmo problema no Windows da mesma forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já resolvi e usei uma solução diferente daquela postada pelo autor da outra questão parecida. Apenas acrescentei `Application.RemoveComponent(Application.Components[i]);` à minha função de fechamento de Forms. Agora funciona corretamente tanto em Android quando em Windows.

FUNÇÃO CORRIGIDA:

```
function TfPrincipal.CloseForms(Sender: TObject): Boolean;
var i: Integer;
begin           
   Result := False;

   try
      for i := 0 to Application.ComponentCount -1 do
         if Application.Components[i] is TForm then
            if TForm(Application.Components[i]).ClassType <> TfPrincipal then begin
               TForm(Application.Components[i]).Close;
               Application.RemoveComponent(Application.Components[i]);  // <<<< ACRESCENTEI ISSO
               Application.ProcessMessages;
            end;

      Result := True;
   except on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Erro fechando forms: ' + E.Message);
   end;
end;
```